# Deploy Django API application with AWS Lambda

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, lambda, django-rest-framework

Is it a way / tutorial how to deploy / convert Existing Django Application (I am using django-rest-famework) for APIs to be available via API Gateway and executed by AWS Lambda functions?

I see package zappa, however I want to avoid it....

Comment: Why is zappa not a good fit? what are your goals? https://serverless.com/ may be an alternative, it supports python.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I did that and it worked out quite fine. If you have any large files (a neural network in my case) you'll have to store them on s3 and load them after the lambda warms up, because there's a quite strict size limit for the project.

Here's a nice tutorial
https://medium.com/@apcelent/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-aws-lambda-53e9c4b137e7